# Nightwatch - Node.js - How to remove/delete HTML elements?

Tags: selenium, automation, nightwatch.js

Apparently, in `Nightwatch`, there's no 'document' or 'window' object.
There is a 'browser' object which seems to be similar.

Tried using `.getElementById()`, `.remove()`, `.removeChild()` and Nightwatch doesn't recognize the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `.execute()` function to write document statements. In the below example I am using the `querySelector` to find the element and then asserting its innertext in the callback.

```
'Nightwatch JS Example': function(browser) {
    browser.url('https://example.com').waitForElementVisible('body').execute(function() {
        return document.querySelector(selector).innerText 
    }, [], function(result) {
        this.assert.equal(result.value, 'Some text')
    })
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
I did think about the .execute() method but didn't have the experience to try it myself.
Thanks for the example .